# los estilos ingresados a css no son compatibles con el html

Tags: html, css

[este es el codigo que fue cargado para mi pagina en html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDzVG.png)
[este es el codigo que fue proporcionado a la pagina de css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq8fW.png)
estoy tratando de que los estilos aparezcan en mi html, pero no le encuentro el error.
que puede estar mal ?

Answer (score 1):

Fijate acá te dejo un ejemplo de una HEAD bástante básico que te puede dar una guía para complemetar el tuyo.

Una de las cosas de atención es el "dónde" se encuetran tus archivos, la ruta a donde apunta el "href=" del tag "link"

```
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <!-- TAGS -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="que hace tu proyecto">
  <meta name="author" content="nombre del autor">

  <!-- TITULO -->    
  <title>Titulo del tab del navegador</title>

  <!-- ICONOS -->
  <link href="images/logos/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link href="images/logos/appleicon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link href="style/vendor/bootstrap/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style/css/mobil.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style/css/social-buttons.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style/css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- LETRAS -->
  <link href="_style/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle|Raleway|Roboto|Lato|Poiret+One|Cantarell|Titan+One|Permanent+Marker|Caveat|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
```

y tal como te comenta ARAN, es buena práctica que pongas el llamado a javascrips al final de tu html antes de la etiqueta de cierre

```
<html lang="en">
    
  <head>
    <link href="style/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    {AQUI EL RESTO DEL CÓDIGO}

    |
    |
    V

    <script src="path/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Espero te sirva
d@p

Answer (score 0):

Olvidaste poner el link en el head de tu archivo HTML?

Por si lo olvidaste, esta es la forma de unir al css con el html:

```
// esto va ubicado en el head de tu archivo HTML
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
```

El atributo href hace referencia a donde es que se encuentra ubicado tu arhivo css. Para este caso es en la ruta ./style.css

PD: es una buena práctica que pongas el script de javascript antes del cierre de la etiqueta de body. Cualquier duda me dices. Saludos.